# Swift locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not prompting the user

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, location, core-location

```swift
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

is called when the user pushes a button, but no prompt is displayed.

Here is my full code

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation



struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var distanceTracker = DistanceTracker();
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: distanceTracker.enableLocServices){
            Text("Enable Location")
        }
        
    }


}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        ContentView()

    }

}


import CoreLocation

class DistanceTracker: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var startLocation: CLLocation!
    var lastLocation: CLLocation!
    @Published var traveledDistance = 0.0
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func enableLocServices(){
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("bruh")
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location permission not asked for yet")

        case .restricted:
            print("Location usage is restricted (perhaps by parental controls or some other restriction)")
        case .denied:
            print("Location permission denied by user")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("Location permission granted for background and foreground use")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Location permission granted for foreground use only")
        @unknown default:
            print("An unknown authorization status received")
        }
    }
}
```

On button press, it prints "bruh". Edit: Also, the status printed is "Location permission not asked for yet"

`NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` are both added to the info section.
[image]

Location services on both the watch and phone are enabled (this is a watchOS only app but still, and I couldn't get this to work for IOS anyway), and the permission was not previously denied. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does any authorisation status get printed?

Comment: @Paulw11 "Location permission not asked for yet"

Comment: @Boio Is that printed before or after the button press? Probable before given your code.

Comment: @HangarRash correct. It prints "Location permission not asked for yet" one time on app launch, then prints "bruh" with every button press

Comment: Add `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)` to your manager class and print the error if any.

Comment: Your question states: *"NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription are both added to the info section."*. But that's not true. You have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, not `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. You need `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with watchOS 9 as well? Anybody here reading this having that problem as well? All usage-descriptions are present, the dialog just never appears.

Comment: I meant watchOS 10 btw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this

```
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
```

You need to add also this:

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```

When you try with this you will see permission pop up.

Comment: Who knows why apple decided to make those identifiers so similar

Comment: @Boio This is why you needed to add `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`. But honestly I'm not sure why your app didn't crash due to the lack of correct privacy entry in Info.plist.